# Programatic styling of UITableViewHeaderFooterView elements within a Nib

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a UITableViewHeaderFooterView as a nib file and added it as a table header to layout a reasonably complex design.

The view is added and work ok - but I'm struggling to trigger programatic styling against objects in the nib file.

For example - i'm trying to add rounded corners to a button -

I've connected the button to the header file - which is below -

**The tableheader.H File**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface TableHeader : UITableViewHeaderFooterView
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *lrgBtn;

@end
```

and added code to style the buttons in the .M file -

**The tableheader.M File**

```
#import "TableHeader.h"

@implementation TableHeader

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Rounded button
        CALayer *btnLayer = [_lrgBtn layer];
        [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];


    }

    return self;
}
```

Above does nothing when compiled - So I figured maybe it's better to place the rounded button code in the viewDidLoad method of the tableview - so I imported the tableview.h file above and  triggered with the following -

```
 TableHeader *tableHead;

CALayer *btnLayer = [tableHead.lrgBtn layer];
[btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
```

Again - this did nowt!  any tips?

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Did it work for you?

Comment: sorry been in a meeting - will give it a go - nice one - cheers

Comment: I have 2 suggestions for you. 1) Try setting AutoLayout Constraints for fixed height and width. 2) Make your button type as Custom(Not Rounded Rect).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the cornerRadius attribute of desired UIControl in XIB itself.

1. Select the control you want to make rounded corner.
2. Add an User Defined Runtime Attribute layer.cornerRadius and then set the value for it.

Note: If you are using Xcode 5 then you need not import QuartzCore framework.

Select the control you want to make rounded corner.

[image: XCode User Defined Runtime Attribute]

Comment: didnt work for me unfortunately - i'm using ios7.1 if thats any help.